# How do I iterate through 10 TextBox's in a GroupBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, tabs, controls, groupbox

I have 10 TextBox's in a GroupBox, in a Tab control. How do I implement Cut, Copy & Paste on all of the TextBox's without accessing each one individually?

Comment: It woul be a pain in the a** to do and might break basic UX functionality...

Comment: Thank you, but I worked it out. I used a controls collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a custom text box that blocks or replaces the cut, copy, paste command:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_CUT   = 0x0300;
    private const int WM_COPY  = 0x0301;
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_CUT:
                // Handle Cut
                return;

            case WM_COPY:  
                // handle copy 
                return;

            case WM_PASTE:
                // handle paste
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```